Installing bumbummen99/shoppingcart in Laravel 11

I am trying to install this package https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart/tree/master in my laravel 11.
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update bumbummen99/shoppingcart
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[1.0, ..., 1.2.1] require illuminate/support ~4 -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.2.17] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with 
another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart 1.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.0.0, ..., 2.1.2] require illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.2.45] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.4] require illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.3.23] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart 2.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart 2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.5.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart 2.5.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.6.39] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.6.0, ..., 2.7.7] require illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.7.28] but these were not 
loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.8.0, ..., 2.8.2] require illuminate/support 5.4.*||5.5.*||5.6.*||5.7.*||5.8.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, 
likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart 2.8.3 requires illuminate/support 5.4.*||5.5.*||5.6.*||5.7.*||5.8.*||6.0.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.8.4, ..., 2.8.9] require illuminate/support 5.4.*||5.5.*||5.6.*||5.7.*||5.8.*||^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - bumbummen99/shoppingcart[2.9.0, ..., 2.9.1] require illuminate/support 5.4.*||5.5.*||5.6.*||5.7.*||5.8.*||^6.0||^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6

Can anyone help me??

bumbummen99/shoppingcart only support Laravel until version 9.x, it hasn't been updated for version 10.x or 11.x. See this line in its composer.json file.
You could either downgrade Laravel to version 9, or use another shopping cart library.
